# ValueError with spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')

Tags: anaconda, spacy, miniconda

I'm getting 
`ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (96) into shape (128)`
for 
`spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')`

I manually downloaded and installed the model as i'm working on a work computer with download restrictions.

I have followed the instructions to download and copy from this link: https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/3113

1. Copy the folder 
   `Python35\lib\site-packages\en_core_web_sm`
   create a folder named en in 
   `Python35\Lib\site-packages\spacy\data`
   , paste the copied contents to en, and rename the folder as en_core_web_sm-2.0.0.
2. Copy the 
   `__init__.py`
   file in en_core_web_sm and paste it in en (that is, the **init**.py file must be in both 
   `Python35\Lib\site-packages\spacy\data\en` and 
   `Python35\Lib\site-packages\spacy\data\en\en_core_web_sm-2.0.0`

I am able to run 
`spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')`
but am giving a ValueError instead. 
Appreciate all help. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error.
Updated spacy to version 2.1.3.
Now it is working properly.

If you are using Anaconda:
conda install -c conda-forge spacy

Answer (score 0):

In order to let you use the en_core_web_sm model via the shortcut link 'en', spaCy creates a symlink. This means you need to have permissions to do this. See here for more details: https://spacy.io/usage/models#usage-link

A note in case others come across this issue later: Copy-pasting the folder and renaming it is really only the last resort if you can't run the command with admin permissions and you need to be able to load the model via spacy.load('en'). This is usually not the case – you can just install the model and load it via its full name, spacy.load('en_core_web_sm'). In fact, I often prefer this syntax, since it's more explicit and you immediately know which model is loaded.

--Copied from the same link you have mentioned in the question. No Copyright violation.

Comment: Thanks. The error ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (96) into shape (128) occurs when i run nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm'). I can't seem to find any explanations on why this error occurs.

Comment: Did you created symlink for the same?

Answer (score 0):

Download en through terminal then use

spacy.load("en_core_web_sm") it will work..

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).